# Erasing Item In std::map with scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, scoped-ptr

Is it safe to remove an item in a std::map with scoped_ptr? Lile,

```
std::map<std::string, boost::scoped_ptr<CFoo*>> lmap;

boost::scoped_ptr<CFoo> item1(new CFoo);
boost::scoped_ptr<CFoo> item2(new CFoo);

lmap["item1"] = item1;
lmap["item2"] = item2;


std::map<std::string, boost::scoped_ptr<CFoo*>>::iterator iter;
iter = lmap.find("item1");
lmap.erase(iter)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. You probably mean `scoped_ptr<CFoo>`.

Comment: is scoped_ptr ever copyable?

Comment: No, you can't copy a `scoped_ptr`.

Comment: The longer I think about it, the more I'm wondering whether this approach is a sensible way to address whatever the problem might be. Why not use a `map <string, CFoo>`? Is `CFoo` so huge that it would cause troubles?